# User Inputs Predefined Variable By It's Name/Character

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to make the board game Battleship as a C++ program in somewhat simple code (still learning C++ but I know the fundamentals and some advanced things here and there) and I'm trying to do something within the game I'm not quite sure how to do. I have a 2D 10x10 array acting as the board currently, looks like this:

```
int board[10][10]={
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19},
{20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29},
{30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39},
{40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49},
{50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59},
{60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69},
{70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79},
{80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89},
{90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99} };
```

The way it's setup at the moment, every row and column number associate with the first and second digits of every number, respectively, so:

```
board[4][5] //This is 45
```

Now I know I can just have the user input the coordinated as just "4" and "5", but wanting to be more traditional to the game, I'm trying to figure out how to make the rows be labeled alphabetically, so "45" would actually technically be "d5". My first attempt at this was this:

```
int d=4, x, y;
cout <<"Input Desired Coordinates";
cin >> x;
cin >> y;
cout << board[x][y];
```

My intention was that if the user inputted "d", it would translate to the variable "d" which has a value of 4, but apparently C++ doesn't work that way, so is there any (reasonably simple) way to be able to input a letter and have the program interpret that as a variable and replace it with the predefined variable's value? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started:

```
char c;
cin >> c;          # If this is the character 'd',
int n = c - 96;    # then this will be the number 4.
```

See, if a byte contains `01100100`, then if we interpret it as a *number*, it's 100, but if we interpret it as a *character*, it's 'd'.

Comment: This is perfect for what I need, thanks a lot, thought with mine I would subtract 97 since, as MKAROL pointed out, arrays start at 0 so I want my 'a' value to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that array in C++ starts from 0. So "d" shoud be equal 3. Also check if X and Y are in range of an array. D is in ASCII under decimal number 97.

```
   unsigned int boardWidth = 10;
   unsigned int boardHeight = 10;
   int X;
   int Y;
   char mid;
   cout << "Input coordinates";
   cin >> mid;
   cin >> Y;
   X = static_cast<int>(mid) - 97;
   if (X < boardWidth && Y < boardHeigth && X > 0 && Y > 0) {
      cout << board[X][Y];
   }
```

Comment: Ahh yeah yeah I'm aware that array's start at 0, sorry that was just a typo on trying to do quick math in my head.

Comment: I like both this solution and Beta's, but I will say this is a little too overly complicated for my needs, but thanks for this (and reminding me that my mental math was off).